# How to get costs in bigquery by job id

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get the cost of each job I run.
I know that in this table billing.gcp_billing_export_v1_XXXXX there is billing information but I can't find a way to connect it by job id. I also know that in this table `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT there is costs info.
Im confused, how can I know what is the right way to calc the costs and how can I get the costs by job id?

I have tried to connect between the 2 above tables but couldn't because they have different granularity.

I need to be able to calculate it automaticlly and not manually with Google Cloud Pricing (GCP) Calculator

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using default on-demand pricing plan, the cost of a query is `$5 per scanned TB` in US region as seen [in BigQuery pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing).

You then get the cost of each job with:

```
select 
  job_id, 
  ifnull(5. * (total_bytes_billed / pow(2, 40)), 0) as job_cost
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
```

(1 TB = 2^40 bytes)